# How to Create an ASP.NET MVC 4 project in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

From microsoft msdn:

> When you use MVC 4 projects in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 RTM, you can open existing projects only in the IDE because the tooling support for MVC 4 is removed in Visual Studio 2015 RTM

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt591926.aspx

Is any one knows some way to Create an ASP.NET MVC 4 project in visual studio 2015?

I also make an empty web application using .net 4 in VS2015 and add mvc4 package from nuget, but cannot make a clean project on it.

Comment: Easiest way is to install Visual Studio 2013 aside to Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Strongly related: [Does Visual Studio 2015 support older versions of MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123609/does-visual-studio-2015-support-older-versions-of-mvc)

Comment: Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the answer [Does Visual Studio 2015 support older versions of MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123609/does-visual-studio-2015-support-older-versions-of-mvc) states you cannot create an older MVC project in Visual Studio 2015 (although they can be opened).

So it is the easiest way to install Visual Studio 2013 and create the project there. Afterwards all work can be done in Visual Studio 2015. If you do not want a side by side installation on your working machine, you can install Visual Studio 2013 in another environment (like a virtual machine).